# Retrofit 400 bad request base64 encoded Image

Tags: android, image, base64, retrofit2

I have the following { @POST("mobile/posts/add")
    Call publish(@QueryMap Map options}
Where one of the options is an encoded based64 string from bitmap image. The server side takes it as a query parameter, but retrofit keeps saying bad request. I have seen some solutions with the multipart, but those ones are not working for me. The server side takes only string query parameters, thus the post should only be sent as @query or @queryMap.
Thanks in advance

Comment: No other information in the response?  Did you add a logging interceptor to see if that tells you anything?

Comment: It is telling me what I wrote above "bad request", although when I send the same request through postman I reach the server at least. But in this case, retrofit doesn't even let the request go out of the phone.

Comment: How do you know it's not leaving the phone?  How about you post your relevant code?